# What are some good ways to close an app without using your mouse/trackpad?

Tags: macos

I have an app that would fail once in a while, and I need to restart it if it doesn't works as expected.

I can use Spotlight to start it after closing it.
But how do I close it quickly using something as efficient as Spotlight?

Answer (score 3):

If the application is active You can press <kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to quit the app. If You want to force quit this app - press  <kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌥ Option</kbd>+<kbd>⎋ Esc</kbd>.

If the app is currently not active hold down <kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd> and navigate to Your app with <kbd>⇥ TAB</kbd>, then without releasing the <kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd> press <kbd>Q</kbd>.

Comment: Force quit is Cmd Option Esc.   There's no Shift.

Comment: @Allan when you press `shift` then there will be no Dialog to choose the app, but current application is Force Quitted.

Comment: I stand corrected.  I

Comment: Not all application can be selected with cmd + tab.